# d3 handle keydown event in multiple charts

Tags: javascript, d3.js, keydown

Looked through this d3 example (http://bl.ocks.org/mbostock/4342190#index.html), keydown event is handled in window level.

What's the best way to handle keydown event seperately if I have multiple d3 charts in one page?

Comment: You would need to attach it to an element.